# CAD Editing plugin in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Is there a plugin with CAD tools for editing vector entities such as lines and polygons in QGIS 3.0?

Comment: Related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314052/qgis-3-update-for-the-cadtools-plugin

Answer (score 4):

There is the Advanced Digitising Tool which is now built in to QGIS 3.x

[image]

There is also the Shape Digitising Toolbar