# CadTools plugin functionality in QGIS 3 beyond Advanced Digitising Panel?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, digitizing, drawing

I've recently migrated to QGIS 3.6.0, and I've realised that the wonderful [CadTools plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cadtools/) is not compatible with QGIS 3.

I tried to use the [Advanced Digitising Panel](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-advanced-digitizing-panel), but it's cumbersome and not practical at all, especially when it comes to drawing land-use plans. For instance, with CadTools, I could easily create arc intersections, but with the Advanced Digitising Panel, I couldn't find a way to do it without losing my mind. The CadTools plugin is super efficient and straightforward to use, and I already miss it so much. I resorted to having both QGIS 2.18.28 and 3.6.0 installed on my computer as a workaround...

Does anyone know if there's a replacement for this plugin or if it'll be converted for QGIS 3?

I contacted the plugin author, but I haven't received any answer, and the [plugin's Github](https://github.com/geopython/CadTools) seems to be dead.

Comment: Yes, please update CadTools for QGIS 3! The Advanced Digitizing Panel is also driving me crazy... I've wasted so much time figuring out how to make arc intersections and other simple things. I badly want to migrate all my projects from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3, but the absence of CadTools forced me to keep QGIS 2.18 installed...

Comment: Who are you asking to update? If the original author isn't interested in updating the plugin, then someone else needs to adopt it, or you'll need to pay someone to update. There's no magic elves who do this work for you ;)

Comment: What about QAD plugin?